# ASP.NET webforms doesn't retrieve query in gridview when using conditionals

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This code will perfectly retrieve data if there are no conditional clauses
(a basic `select * from table` statement), but it fails when I provide username and order by clause

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString());
    string cname = TextBox2.Text;

    Session[cname] = cname.ToString();

    con.Open();
        
    string sql = " select * from customer_reservations where customer_id='" 
                 + Session[cname] + "' order by reservation_time  ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    /*"select *from customer_reservations where customer_id='" + cname +
         "' order by reservation_time";
    */

    /* select *from customer_reservations */
}
```

The `reservation_time` is stored as `datetime` data type in SQL Server and does seem accessible because when I do a `select *` statement it does convert 14' O clock to 2pm in browser

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @marc_s   string sql = " select *from customer_reservations where customer_id=@custm_id ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("custm_id", custname);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: MUCH BETTER !! Now check this out, too:  you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s    still doesnt work. rebuild the build as well.   ```string cname = TextBox2.Text;
            Session["custname"] = cname;
            
            
            string sql = " select *from customer_reservations where customer_id=@custm_id ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("custm_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=cname;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();     ```

Comment: @marc_s  i am only a week into the .net framework so i cant say for sure but, i cant find resources online for making custom queries to db using .net webforms. but if you do know a similar solution/article like my problem; please share. regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, is cname text, or a number? You have to check the database.

However, it always VERY easy to mess up string concatenation, and thus I suggest this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString()))
            {
            string cname = TextBox2.Text;
            Session["cname"] = cname.ToString();

            con.Open();
            string sql = " select * from customer_reservations where customer_id = @cname "
                         + " order by reservation_time";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cname;

            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }
```

So, it tends to be easier to write out the sql without all those quotes and what not. And bonus is we get sql injection safe code.

So try above.

Also, check your on-page load event. If it loads up the grid, or does anything, then you ALWAYS, but ALWAYS want to ONLY have code run on first page load, and hence this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }
```

As a FYI, you would have needed this:

```
 Session["cname"] = cname;
```

And to get the value out, you need this:

```
 some var = Session["cname"].ToString();
```

You actually creating a session var of the actual text value!! - not something called "cname".

2nd FYI:

If you want to use paging on the grid, then you can't give the GV a "reader", and thus you need/should use this:

```
                string sql = " select * from customer_reservations where customer_id = @cname "
                             + " order by reservation_time";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cname;

                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```